# Exception Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: spring, eclipse, hibernate, maven

In general, I will try to describe the problem. A working project stopped working at one point. Revised and tried many options with from other posts until nothing helped. That's what comes out:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Tabelle "USER" nicht gefunden
Table "USER" not found; SQL statement:
insert into user (ID, AKTIV, PASSWORD, START, USERROLE, USERNAME, VERSION) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7599)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1747)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1154)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 135 common frames omitted`
```

Here is the class code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column( name = "ID" )
private Long id;
@Version
@Column( name = "VERSION")
private int version;
@Column( name = "USERNAME" )
private String username;
@Column( name = "PASSWORD" )
private String password;
@Column( name = "START" )
private String start;
@Column( name = "AKTIV" )
private String aktiv;
@Column( name = "USERROLE" )
private String userRole;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private EmployeeEntity employeeEntity;
    
}
```

Tests stopped working, throwing the following error. The file is on the path: src/main/resources

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Here is the integration of the file into the project:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.m_landalex.dataconvert.petsistence")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.m_landalex.dataconvert")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Configuration
public class AppServiceConfig { ... }
```

After a small revision, a new error appears. The feeling is that Maven does not see my resource folders.

```
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.m_landalex.dataconvert.petsistence")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.m_landalex.dataconvert")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@Configuration
public class AppServiceConfig { ... }
```

The file is on the path: src/test/resources/db
Exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db/clean-up.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db/test-data.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Test method:

```
    @SqlGroup( { @Sql( value = "classpath:db/test-data.sql",
        config = @SqlConfig( encoding = "utf-8", separator = ";", commentPrefix = "--" ),
        executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD ),
        @Sql( value = "classpath:db/clean-up.sql",
        config = @SqlConfig( encoding = "utf-8", separator = ";", commentPrefix = "--" ),
        executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD) } )
@Test
public void fetchAllTest() {
    List<AbstractObject> returnedList = defaultService.fetchAll();
    assertNotNull(returnedList);
    assertEquals(2, returnedList.size());
}
```

After adding

```
 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
```

the application started to run. My tests remained a problem -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'h2.hibernate.dialect' in value "${h2.hibernate.dialect}"
```

and the same configuration file is used

Comment: Have you made any changes to the POM? Clearly, the project classpath is not properly configured. Try re-importing the project as a Maven project

Comment: @crizzis thanks for helping, during this time I have localized and solved the problem. Project->Build Path->Build Path Config->Source->  src/main/resources and src/test/resources. Go to the apparently default settings Excluded:**; in both places I registered Excluded(None) and it worked. I just can't understand why the settings rolled back.

Comment: @crizzis Moreover, this happened with absolutely all projects in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a reserved keyword, so you must use square brackets to make it explicit that you mean the *object* named "user" it, i.e. use `[user]` instead of `user`.

Comment: I tried it with square brackets, changed the table name completely - nothing helped. I forgot to clarify that in parallel with this project, all the others fell apart.